# countrycode package not recognizing "SOM" as ISO3 character code for Somalia - r

Tags: r, country-codes

I am getting a strange result trying to convert from ISO3 character code to World Bank Code. Notably Somalia is not recognized in ISO3

Somalia ISO3 character code is "SOM": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3

Example:

```
library(countrycode)
place <- data.frame("iso3c" = "SOM")

place
  iso3c
1   SOM

place$wb <- countrycode(sourcevar = place$iso3c, origin = "iso3c", destination = "wb")
Warning message:
In countrycode(sourcevar = place$iso3c, origin = "iso3c", destination = "wb") :
  Some values were not matched unambiguously: SOM

place
  iso3c   wb
1   SOM <NA>
```

Since World Bank code for Somalia is also SOM, I can get around this by setting `nomatch = NULL`.

```
place$wb <- countrycode(sourcevar = place$iso3c, origin = "iso3c", destination = "wb", nomatch = NULL)
place
  iso3c  wb
1   SOM SOM
```

But this behavior still seems wrong. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. I submitted an [issue here](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode/issues/203).

I would argue the most preferable current workaround (until it's fixed) would be...

```
place$wb <- countrycode(sourcevar = place$iso3c, origin = "iso3c", destination = "wb", custom_match = c("SOM" = "SOM"))
```

which makes it extremely clear what is happening, and easy to remove if/when the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that, for some reason, there isn't any code for Somalia in the World Bank dictionary `wb`:

```
countrycode::codelist[227, c("country.name.en", "iso3c", "wb")]
#     country.name.en iso3c   wb
# 227         Somalia   SOM <NA>
```

Also,

```
table(is.na(countrycode::codelist[227, ]))
#
# FALSE  TRUE 
#   678     3
```

where those three `NA` cases are

```
#     eu28   wb wb.name
# 227 <NA> <NA>    <NA>
```

So, it looks like quite a coincidence. However, we also have that

```
grep("wb", colnames(countrycode::codelist))
# [1] 53 54 55 56 57
```

with

```
countrycode::codelist[227, 53:57]
#       wb wb_api.name wb_api2c wb_api3c wb.name
# 227 <NA>     Somalia       SO      SOM    <NA>
```

so that perhaps you can use `wb_api3c` instead:

```
(place$wb <- countrycode(sourcevar = place$iso3c, origin = "iso3c", destination = "wb_api3c"))
# [1] "SOM"
```

although `countrycode::codelist[, "wb_api3c"]` also has a number of missing values.

Comment: This is great, but why does the wb library have no code or wb.name for Somalia? World Bank data sets certainly use certainly use Country.Code: SOM: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD; other databases also have this country code: https://irows.ucr.edu/research/tsmstudy/wbcountrycodes.htm. Is this a bug in the library?

Comment: @MorrisseyJ, I have zero knowledge about this but, e.g., in your first link we reach Somalia through https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?locations=SO, i.e., with SO, which looks like `wb_api2c`. So, perhaps there are indeed different subcategories within the World Bank dictionary. Perhaps you can ask [here](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode/issues) on what's the reason behind this choice in the package.